# Selenium:Both wait and get element when ready

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

Instead of doing 2 steps:

```
wait.until(webDriver -> webDriver.findElement(By.id("userTable")));
```

and then retrieving the element when it's ready:

```
WebElement x = webDriver.findElement(By.id("userTable"));
```

can this be done in one step?

For instance,I don't want to do :

```
wait.until(webDriver -> webDriver.findElement(By.id("userTable")).findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"userTable\"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a"))).click();
```

but would like to break it down into steps because it's clearer:

That is first wait fo it to be ready:

```
wait.until(webDriver -> webDriver.findElement(By.id("userTable")));
```

then get a reference to it:

```
WebElement x = webDriver.findElement(By.id("userTable"));
```

and then get the child element:

```
x.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id=\"userTable\"]/tbody/tr/td[1]/a"))).click();
```

So can the **wait** and **getting the reference** parts be somehow joined in one step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`until` method returns `<T>` which is generic and based on return type you provide in the lambda expression. Since `findElement` returns `WebElement`, the return type of `until` method will also be `WebElement`.

With provided implementation, you already solved your problem as `until` will return `WebElement` or throw `TimeoutException`

Just save the reference to a variable:

```
WebElement userTable = wait.until(webDriver -> webDriver.findElement(By.id("userTable")));
```

Answer (score 0):

As your usecase is to invoke `click()` you can induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) inconjunction with [ExpectedConditions](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("#userTable>tbody>tr td:nth-child(2)>a"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='userTable']/tbody/tr/td[1]/a"))).click();
  ```